# How to use the Front Page module

Tags: 8

I am currently trying to make my front page viewable by anonymous users, I am using the [Front Page](https://www.drupal.org/project/front) module to do this in Drupal 8, however I am unsure how to use it?

Comment: Does this really require a module?

Comment: I'm using this one https://www.drupal.org/project/front

Comment: Sorry, I misread what you said earlier and apparently so, unless you know another way?

Comment: You can set any Node as the front page in the site settings. You can also create a View page and set that too. I'm just not sure why a module is needed for this.

Comment: Sorry I'm very new to Drupal, so i'm struggling. Permission settings are still not allowing the anonymous user to just view the home page.

Comment: Then there is some config or module altering that behavior because vanilla Drupal does not restrict front page access to anonymous users by default.

Answer (score 1):

The default front page Drupal uses is a view which lists several pieces of content (nodes). This view is by default visisble for authenticated and anonymous users and you do not require a module for it.

The front page module is only useful if you want to show a different page to users depending on their role. For instance you can configure the front page anonymous user to be `/anon-front` and for authenticated user `/auth-front`. It does not do anything with permissions but simply redirects the user when they click the home link.

In your case it seems that anonymous users are not able to see the default front page. There are two likely reasons for this:

- All your nodes are private and anonymous users are not allowed to view any nodes.
- The views configuration has been altered and the view is only visible for authenticated users.

You do not need to use the front page module (at least not the way the question is currently written), but without further information we cannot help you debug either.

Answer (score 0):

If I recall correctly, you can go to the configuration page, and in the anonymous users section, you can choose 'alias'.

-- edit --

I just installed the D8 version of the module. It's a little different from D7, probably because it's still an alpha version and incomplete.

Go to Admin -> Configuration -> Front Page -> settings

Under "Front page for anonymous user", check 'enable', and enter the path to the page you want anonymous users to see.

I don't know if it will work or not though, since it's an alpha version, it may not be ready for usage.

Comment: There is not an option for this. I'm still struggling to allow anonymous users to view the home page.

Comment: I edited my answer.